# How would you optimize this 2 milion records table or queries?

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, memory-optimized-tables, query-performance

I have a relatively large **InnoDB** table that contains domain names, I want to track when they expire, their traffic rank, owner email, and many parameters like that.

Currently I have around 2 million records, I intend to keep it under 5 million.

I wonder if there is anything else I can do to optimize it, currently a query like this **takes around 4-8 seconds**:

```
SELECT * 
FROM domains 
WHERE domain_whois_date > 0 
ORDER BY domain_whois_status asc 
LIMIT 500
```

I consider that memory and caching related options I set in my.cnf work decently because if I quickly run the same query again it loads in few ms. But table updates very often and most queries are not cached and take longer (so I understand).

So far my best solution is to create a memory based table, a mirror of `domains` called `domains_cache` and run searches in that; but seems to crash often, I think it's because this memory table takes almost 100% of ram. 
Is this the right approach ?

Main InnoDB table takes around 500MB, memory table with same data uses around 2GB.
Running on CentOS virtual machine, 2 cores, 4GB ram.

[image]

Comment: Is the `SELECT *` required, or do you only use some of the columns?

Comment: The `WHERE domain_whois_date > 0` makes little if any sense at all. @adrianTNT how can a date by 0 or negative?

Comment: @WillemRenzema I use them all, displaying domains in a table, I think it only makes sense to skip some columns if they would be large `text` type values, I think* :)

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ that part indeed is kind of remaining junk from something else; I didn't get what you meant about date by 0.

Comment: He means all practical values for date will be gt 0. The operator is pointless. You're only going to find efficiency on sorting unless you paginate with logical boundaries. Limit N is not scalable and you will see more benefit with better filtering to reduce scan times.

Comment: How many different values of `status`?  Could/should it be normalized?  What percentage have `date > 0`?  What do you do with the 500?  Delete them?  Move on to the next 500?  Do you need all the columns?  Each of these questions could lead to an optimization that takes advantage of the data and/or activity.

Answer (score 1):

Please create the following index

```
create index domains_ix_status_date on domains (domain_whois_status,domain_whois_date);
```

We're traversing through the index where the rows are already ordered by the way we want them (`ORDER BY domain_whois_status`), we check the condition `domain_whois_date > 0` (still within the index structure) and we retrieve only the relevant rows and output them.

Answer (score 1):

In any SQL queries, sequence will be next:

first, select target records:

```
WHERE domain_whois_date > 0
```

then sort result:

```
ORDER BY domain_whois_status asc
```

and only after - take some number of records for return to client:

```
LIMIT 500
```

so, in table with 2M records, big part of them will be have Unix date > 0
not many domain was created before - **1/1/1970**
and You sort all this records without indexes

You can create or

```
index for - (domain_whois_date,domain_whois_status)
```

or at least index for

```
domain_whois_status
```

If most of Your **domain_whois_date** - positive